# json распарсить из php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

формирую вот такой json

```
return response()->json(['datam' => $smessage->created_at, 'photo' => Auth::user()->attributes->photo])
```

в js пробую распарсить так

```
var parse_data = JSON.parse(data);
alert(parse_data['datam']);
```

но выдает

```
VM1804:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Это потому что data не строка json, а обычный объект, можете увидеть это из примера:

```js
try {
  JSON.parse({ datam: '123' })
} catch ({ message }) {
  console.log(message)
}
```

Comment: ага, а как получить данные? что-то не могу вникнуть

Comment: @Aslero ваши данные и есть `data` – `alert(data.datam)`. Их не надо парсить, они приходят сразу объектом

Comment: ай блин, спасибо

Comment: все ровно выводит object Object

Comment: Выведите через console.log(...), alert преобразует к строке)

Comment: а почему при выводе даты из базы он добавляет нули? 
2018-09-25 10:03:27.000000